# Is there a way to send parameters from angular login page to Kibana iframe dashboard?

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, kibana

i'm new to the ELK stack , so i have an angular web application that displays iframe kibana dashboard , so my problem is that kibana asks for user and password in the application and i have already a login page in the web app so the user has to enter his credentials twice , is there a way that i can  pass parameters to the iframe kibana dashboard so the user won't have to log in to kibana?

Answer (score 0):

If Kibana and Your Application is on the same domain, you can use javascript to submit login form inside iFrame from your application's page where you are loading kibana in iFrame.

By this, you can log in to the Kibana inside iFrame.